# Why does this Azure CLI boolean property query seem to be backwards?

Tags: json, bash, azure-cli, jmespath, azure-cloud-shell

I am writing a simple az command to return the default version of AKS. I have tried several variation as below, but the result set returned is the opposite of what I am after. Is there something I am missing with regards to the JMESPath filter expression and boolean values in the JSON?

These two commands, I would have thought, should return only the 'default' version. Instead, they return all but the default.

```bash
az aks get-versions -l $region --query "orchestrators[?default==true].[orchestratorVersion,default]" -o table
```

and

```bash
az aks get-versions -l $region --query "orchestrators[?default==true].{Version:orchestratorVersion,IsDefault:default}" -o table
```

In the end I used !=null filter instead, but would like to know the answer.

The data without the filter

```bash
az aks get-versions -l $region --query "orchestrators[].{Version:orchestratorVersion,IsDefault:default}" -o json
```

is as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.10.12"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.10.13"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.11.9"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.11.10"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.12.7"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.12.8"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.13.11"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": true,
    "Version": "1.13.12"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.14.7"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.14.8"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.15.4"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": null,
    "Version": "1.15.5"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rule in the JEMSPATH, you can see the description [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/1c9c35cf681b6605d8629e5ce8865221a4fd2a30/docs/proposals/functions.rst), it's the Raw type this [document](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/blob/1c9c35cf681b6605d8629e5ce8865221a4fd2a30/docs/proposals/functions.rst). And it shows below:

[image]

There is also a difference between PowerShell and Shell.

In PowerShell, you can just use the "``" in the command like this:

```
az aks get-versions -l $region --query "orchestrators[?default == ``true``].[orchestratorVersion,default]" -o table
```

But in Shell, you need to use the "`" and make change like this:

```
az aks get-versions -l $region --query 'orchestrators[?default == `true`].[orchestratorVersion,default]' -o table
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did read the JMESPath doc and thought I had tried every permutation!
Didn't realise that using double quotes in Bash screwed it all up and never tried PowerShell.